# How to check if objects are hidden in godot

Tags: godot

I have multiple objects, each has area2d and collision shape, I click it, I hide it.

Now, I create script and attach it to the main Node2d with the following

```
extends Node2D


func _ready():
    if (get_node("matchbox_closed").hide() && get_node("oil").hide()):
            get_node("match").show()
```

it hides the first object in the list automatically, what I want is to check not to hide, but I can't see any boolean that check that or any `isvisible` getter like Libgdx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From a [Godot QA post](https://godotengine.org/qa/3558/how-to-check-whether-a-node-is-active) there should be a method `is_visible()`. Try `get_node("node").is_visible()`. Looking at the docs this method seems to apply to `CanvasItem`, though so perhaps you have to use `CanvasItem`s if you want to check visibility.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation shows that both [CanvasItem](http://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_canvasitem.html#class-canvasitem-visible) and [Spatial](http://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_spatial.html#class-spatial-visible) have a `visible` property.

Note that `CanvasItem` is a parent class to both `Control` (used for GUI) and `Node2d` (used for 2d).  When considered with `Spatial` (used for 3d) this means `visible` is available for most nodes that can be drawn.